# String to ArrayList<Long>

Tags: java, java-stream

Currently i have:

```
String a = "123.5950,555,5973.1,6321.905,6411.810000000001,6591.855"
```

I can turn it into an array list of Strings then into array list of Longs:

```
ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split(","));
ArrayList<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();

for(String ks : vals){
       longs.add(Long.parseLong(ks));
}
```

I tried to do this with `Stream` to make this more 'fun' but cant seem to be successful with this:

```
ArrayList<Long> longs = a.stream().map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I dont think the for loop is very elegant, how can i do it with `Stream`?

Edit: copied to original string wrong

Comment: Your approach doesnt look wrong. But you assign it to a variable of type ``ArrayList``, which it probably isnt. Might that be the issue?

Comment: I don't see how your original code could work. Those aren't longs.

Comment: what do "." and "," mean in the original string?

Comment: @JamesKPolk i had miscopied the string, should be decimal places and comas

Comment: You can't have decimal places in a long.

Comment: How is your `for` loop not elegant?  It's a one-liner!  You can hardly get any more elegant than that.  Plus it's about 2/3 the number of characters as your attempted stream expression...

Comment: You seem to have a special affinity to `ArrayList`. There is no need to copy the `List<String>` returned by `Arrays.asList(…)` into a new `ArrayList<String>`, when you only want to iterate over it. In fact, it’s not even necessary to wrap the array returned by `a.split(",")` via `Arrays.asList(…)`. You could just write `for(String ks : a.split(",")) longs.add(Long.parseLong(ks));`. With the Stream API, you run into the same trope. Don’t declare the variable type as `ArrayList`, when you just need a `List`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a stream from the result of `String.split`:

```
final List<Long> longs = Arrays
            .stream(a.split(","))
            .map(Long::parseLong)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, `Collectors.toList()` will return the `List` interface, not the concrete implementation `ArrayList`.

If you really need an array list, you'll need to copy it:

```
new ArrayList<>(longs);
```

Edit:
As @shmosel pointed out, you can collect directly to an array list with `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Comment: Or `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Answer (score 4):

You can't stream a `String` without splitting it up. Two ways to split to stream:

```
Arrays.stream(a.split(","))
```

or

```
Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(a)
```

Aside from that, `collect(Collectors.toList())` returns `List`, not `ArrayList`. And I'm not sure why you expect `parseLong()` to work on those strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "123.5950.555,5973.1,6321.905,6411.810000000001,6591.855";
List<Double> doubleList = Arrays.stream(a.split(","))
        .map(Doubles::tryParse)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(doubleList);
```

Note: this uses [`Doubles#tryParse`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#tryParse-java.lang.String-) from Guava.

Comment: You should probably mention you're using Guava. And that it'll return some nulls.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @shmosel.